# Inserting a Sum of in a SQL View based on another column from the same View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I am trying to create a view in SQL for a user. (as shown below) In this i would like to Sum the values of dbo.WipPartBook.QtySupplied when the values for the column dbo.WipPartBook.Job are same.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.vwSTKCF.StockCode, dbo.vwSTKCF.Cavity, dbo.vwSTKCF.Mass, dbo.vwSTKCF.Material, dbo.WipPartBook.Job, 
                  dbo.WipPartBook.QtySupplied, dbo.WipPartBook.TrnDate
FROM         dbo.WipPartBook INNER JOIN
                  dbo.InvMaster INNER JOIN
                  dbo.WipMaster ON dbo.InvMaster.StockCode = dbo.WipMaster.StockCode ON dbo.WipPartBook.Job = dbo.WipMaster.Job LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.vwSTKCF ON dbo.InvMaster.StockCode = dbo.vwSTKCF.StockCode
WHERE     (dbo.vwSTKCF.StockCode = 'SC2020-01-00')
ORDER BY dbo.vwSTKCF.StockCode
```

Comment: could you please give some sample data to make it easier to give you an optimized query? thanks

Answer (score 0):

What SQL Server version are you using? If it is a current one you should look into window functions that allow, among others, totals partitioned by a "grouping" column (dbo.WipPartBook.Job)
Look here for an introduction: [Microsoft BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Edit: added an (untested) example:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.vwSTKCF.StockCode, dbo.vwSTKCF.Cavity, dbo.vwSTKCF.Mass, dbo.vwSTKCF.Material, dbo.WipPartBook.Job, 
              dbo.WipPartBook.QtySupplied, dbo.WipPartBook.TrnDate,

SUM(dbo.WipPartBook.QtySupplied) OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.WipPartBook.Job) AS Total

FROM         dbo.WipPartBook INNER JOIN
              dbo.InvMaster INNER JOIN
              dbo.WipMaster ON dbo.InvMaster.StockCode = dbo.WipMaster.StockCode ON dbo.WipPartBook.Job = dbo.WipMaster.Job LEFT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.vwSTKCF ON dbo.InvMaster.StockCode = dbo.vwSTKCF.StockCode
WHERE     (dbo.vwSTKCF.StockCode = 'SC2020-01-00')
ORDER BY dbo.vwSTKCF.StockCode
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dbo.WipPartBook.Job, sum(dbo.WipPartBook.QtySupplied)    
  FROM dbo.WipMaster    
  JOIN dbo.WipPartBook
           ON dbo.WipPartBook.Job = dbo.WipMaster.Job 
 WHERE dbo.WipMaster.StockCode = 'SC2020-01-00'
 GROUP BY dbo.WipPartBook.Job
 Order BY dbo.WipPartBook.Job
```